# Modules in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, modularity

As propably many of you know, there are apps out there (at least in the Android eco-system I know some) that can be extended by installing other add-on/module apps alongside the "main" app.

As a example there is [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) for Android which can be extended with support for [Mega](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer.plugins.mega) or [USB OTG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer.plugins.otg) by installing the respective apps.

Now my question is, is something like this possible with Xamarin.Forms? And if yes, how? Are there examples on this topic?

Comment: In Xamarin.forms, you could try to use `File Picker`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did not ask how to use a file picker.

Comment: Not possible. There can't be a solution for xamarin.forms, unless each platform supports app plug-ins. Given Apple's strictness with iOS for security reasons, I don't see this ever happening on iOS. In which case, its quite unlikely Xamarin.Forms will ever support it. And trying to make a cross-platform way to build plug-ins is likely to be very, very difficult. And a major security risk. Won't happen in native apps - would have to be a browser-based app.

Comment: Note that anything you can do on Android, you can do in Xamarin.Android, and then add as Android-only functionality via a DependencyService in the Android project of your Xamarin.Forms solution. (On other platforms, you would query for that DependencyService, and receive a response saying it does not exist. Your cross-platform Xamarin.Forms code would test for that missing DependencyService.)  Alternatively, you create a "dummy" DependencyService that does nothing. In the case of plug-ins, on iOS, it would always return an empty list of plug-ins.